# Add count row in dataframe with 2nd dataframe row condition

Tags: python

I am counting how many times an ID (foreign key) comes in a dataframe base on the condition of second dataframe where this ID is an unique KEY.

**dataframe 1**

Sno ,  WD , f_id , Date , amount , .......
[image]

**dataframe 2**

[image]

I am trying to do:

df2['attempts'] = df.count(df2.loc[ (df2['f_id'] == df['id'] ), 'id'])

Comment: Please provide your data example as data (or code to create it) and not an image. If AKash_KUmar's example dataframes are good minimal examples for your problem, you can (and should) copy and edit them back into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get you completely but what i feel you want something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'f_id': [11,12,13,11,14,12,11]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [11,12,13,14,15,16,17],'name': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})
count_val = []
for index,row in df2.iterrows() :
    try :
        count = df['f_id'].value_counts()[row['id']]
        #print(str(count))
        count_val.append(count)
    except KeyError :
        count_val.append(0)
df2['count_val'] = count_val
print(df2)
```